# Ports exposed even though it is not defined in kubelet manifest.yaml file

Tags: docker, kubernetes, networking

There are two kubelet nodes and each kubelet node contains several containers including server with wildfly. Even though I do not define containerPort <> hostPort, the management console can be reached with port 9990 from outside. I do not have any clue, why?

```
- name: server
  image: registry/server:develop-latest
  ports:
    - name: server-https
      containerPort: 8443
      hostPort: 8443
```

In docker container inspect <container-id> I see:

```
"ExposedPorts": {
    "9990/tcp": {},
     ...
```

So,

- Why container port 9990 is exposed? and
- Why containerPort 9990 is mapped to hostPort and I can reach the port 9990 from outside?

Comment: Are you doing `docker image inspect` or `docker container inspect` ?

Comment: In either case your image or container exposed ports does not mean you Kubernetes ports are exposed. When we create an image using `dockerfile` there is an option to configure the port number to be exposed. For example in this link - https://hub.docker.com/layers/mongo/library/mongo/latest/images/sha256-f548240f5a61d1ecfe4c16cc73c8a12c1701bf9d47d0121f110dd5655ebefd55?context=explore at the very bottom you can see the portnumber 27017 is set as exposed.

Comment: ^^ it means the ports are exposed inside the docker / pod.. unless you expose it thru `service` in kubernetes only side car container can access it inside the pod.

Comment: I did ```docker container inspect <container-id>```.  I am familiar with dockerfile docs, i.e. neither in dockerfile nor on start I exposed port 9990. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose the port in two places, when you run the container, and when you build the image. Typically you only do the latter since exposing the port is documentation of what ports are likely listening for connections inside the container (it doesn't have any affect on networking).

To see if the port was exposed at build time, you can run:

```bash
docker image inspect registry/server:develop-latest
```

And if that port wasn't exposed in your build, then it was likely exposed in your base image.

Comment: I have checked and the port ```"9990/tcp": {}``` is exposed in docker base image, which clears the first question. Why I reach my container from outside is still not clear, as in kubelet manifest.yaml file no port mapping for ```9990```  is defined.

Comment: If I check the host port 9990 with ```lsof -i :9990``` it refers to a java process which is started by server/container. Does it mean that the java process started by container is not isolated correctly?

Comment: @1c0DevPi too many unknowns to answer your second question. Is the process the same one that's inside of a container, is the container running in docker or another CRI. If it's deployed as a docker container, what settings were used to deploy it? If it's deployed in kubernetes, what pod settings are used, and service/ingress settings? Is the lsof command returning a public or non-routeable IP of the container? I believe this is too open ended for a SO question.

Answer (score 0):

`...I can reach the port 9990 from outside?`

Presumed "outside" here means the host network; then `hostNetwork: true` in your pod spec would allow that in this case.

Otherwise, please post the complete spec and describe the url/endpoint you used to "reach the port 9990" in your question.